# Get first date from timestamp in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I have in my Moodle `db` `table` for every `session` `sessid` and `timestart`. The table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | sessid | timestart  |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      3 | 1456819200 |
|  2 |      3 | 1465887600 |
|  3 |      3 | 1459839600 |
|  4 |      2 | 1457940600 |
|  5 |      2 | 1460529000 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

How to get for `every` `session` the `first` `date` from the `timestamps` in `SQL`?

Comment: Do you need in output `sessid/timestart` or `id/sessid/timestart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easy use this:

```
select sessid,min(timestart) FROM mytable GROUP by sessid;
```

**And for your second question, something like this:**

```
SELECT
  my.id,
  my.sessid,
  IF(my.timestart = m.timestart, 'yes', 'NO' ) AS First,
  my.timestart
FROM mytable my
LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT sessid,min(timestart) AS timestart FROM mytable GROUP BY sessid
  ) AS m ON m.sessid = my.sessid;
```

Comment: How to display if it is the `first date` simply as `yes` or `no`? Thanks.

Comment: i hav extend my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select sessid, min(timestart) as timestart
from your_table_name
group by sessid;
```

Just an other perspective if you need even the `id`.

```
select t.id, t.sessid, t.timestart from
(
    select id, sessid, timestart, 
    (
        case sessid when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := sessid end 
    ) as rn 
    from your_table_name t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by sessid,id
)t
where t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: And how to compare the `timestart` in sessid? Something like ´CASE WHEN mytbl.timestart < "theothertimestarts in the session" THEN Yes ELSE No END´? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    tbl 
WHERE
    (sessid, timestart) IN (
        SELECT tbl2.sessid, MIN(tbl2.timestart) 
        FROM tbl tbl2 
        WHERE tbl.sessid = tbl2.sessid
    );
```